# screen says "copy mode aborted" when I ctr-c number

Tags: gnu-screen

Trying to move between screens in screen.  I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> then the screen number I want.  It doesn't work and the top of the screen says "copy mode aborted".  What's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Num Lock is off.  It's as simple as that.

Comment: So, how to use it to solve the problem?

Comment: Hit the NumLock button on your keyboard.